# Compare software versions in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, version, version-sort

Is there a way to compare software version (e.g. X.Y.Z > A.B.C) in Postgres ? I'm searching for a function on string/varchar or a "version" type.

I found out that http://pgxn.org/dist/semver/doc/semver.html, but I'm looking for alternatives (not so easy to deploy..)

Comment: debian created an extension for this. `debversion` http://pgxn.org/dist/debversion/  for debian based systems deployment is easy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can split the version to array and then do [array comparison](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html).

```
select regexp_split_to_array(v1, '\.')::int[] v1, 
       regexp_split_to_array(v2, '\.')::int[] v2,
       regexp_split_to_array(v1, '\.')::int[] > regexp_split_to_array(v2, '\.')::int[] cmp
from versions;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/697d0/3)

Comment: Comparing string arrays doesn't work any better than simply comparing the strings - you still get things like `'1.9' > '1.10'`. You probably want to cast your `split` output to `int[]`.

Comment: @NickBarnes, great catch! The answer has been updated per your suggestion.

Comment: An issue that might occur is if the version has a postfix to it, i.e. 1.0.0-beta (which is valid for a semver).
A workaround would be removing all non number or dots, and prefixing with "0" just in case. 
TLDR: This link is more robust : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d32c/2/0

Comment: @EdmondLafay-David Thanks this looks more robust compared to `string_to_array` wondering what is the performance cost, Also is it possible to sort just 1 column and get latest vs comparing 1 column to another ?

Answer (score 44):

Use [**`string_to_array()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE). No need for expensive regular expressions.

```sql
SELECT string_to_array(v1, '.')::int[] AS v1
     , string_to_array(v2, '.')::int[] AS v2
     ,(string_to_array(v1, '.')::int[] > string_to_array(v2, '.')::int[]) AS cmp
FROM   versions;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aTjI5GGi)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/44b7c)</sub>

Assuming all parts of the version number are valid integer numbers, of course.

Comment: I think this has the same drawback as the accepted answer.  `'1.9' > '1.10'`, but you want that reversed for semver.

Comment: @EricHu: You may have missed the cast to `int[]`. Hence `1.10 > 1.9`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter whats the best way to do this in version postgres 11!?

Comment: @ProgramCpp: This is the best way in any version.

Answer (score 5):

As already suggested an easy way is to work with a numeric format of the version.
The variable 'server_version_num' contains a numeric format of the version.

Eg.

- version 9.5.2 => 90502
- version 9.6.0 => 90600
- version 10.5  => 100500

  select current_setting('server_version_num')

return a number that can be easily compared with another version number.

Answer (score 5):

Going a bit further [Erwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24249958/6320039), we can create a function to compare a software version with a requirement (like [in ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html)). I've written a function that does just that, to use it:

```sql
SELECT semver_match('4.2.0', '>= 4.0'); -- TRUE
```

Here's the code and tests:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION semver_match(version text, req text) RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    AS $$ 
    SELECT CASE
    WHEN req LIKE '~>%' THEN
        string_to_array(version, '.')::int[] >= string_to_array(substring(req from 4), '.')::int[]
        AND
        string_to_array(version, '.')::int[] <
        -- increment last item by one. (X.Y.Z => X.Y.(Z+1))
        array_append(
            (string_to_array(substring(req from 4), '.')::int[])[1:(array_length(string_to_array(req, '.'), 1) - 1)], -- X.Y
            (string_to_array(substring(req from 4), '.')::int[])[array_length(string_to_array(req, '.'), 1)] + 1 -- Z + 1
        )
 WHEN req LIKE '>=%' THEN string_to_array(version, '.')::int[] >= string_to_array(substring(req from 4), '.')::int[]
    WHEN req LIKE '<=%' THEN string_to_array(version, '.')::int[] <= string_to_array(substring(req from 4), '.')::int[]
    WHEN req LIKE '>%' THEN string_to_array(version, '.')::int[] > string_to_array(substring(req from 3), '.')::int[]
    WHEN req LIKE '<%' THEN string_to_array(version, '.')::int[] < string_to_array(substring(req from 3), '.')::int[]
   WHEN req LIKE '=%' THEN 
        (string_to_array(version, '.')::int[])[1:array_length(string_to_array(substring(req from 3), '.'), 1)] = 
        string_to_array(substring(req from 3), '.')::int[]
    ELSE NULL
    END $$;

-- tests.
SELECT 
    ver,
    req,
    CASE WHEN semver_match(ver, req) = expected
    THEN '✅' ELSE '❌' END AS test_passed
FROM (VALUES
    ('2.3',   '>= 2.3',   TRUE),
    ('2.3.1', '> 2.3',    TRUE),
    ('2.3.1', '< 2.3.2',  TRUE),
    ('2.3.1', '~> 2.3.2', FALSE),
    ('2.4.3', '~> 2.3.2', FALSE),
    ('2.3.2', '~> 2.3.2', TRUE),
    ('2.3.2', '= 2.3.2',  TRUE),
    ('2.3.2', '= 2.3',    TRUE),
    ('2.3.2', '= 2.4',    FALSE)
) AS _ (ver, req, expected)
```

See [my blogpost on that topic](https://ulysse.md/2021/11/25/Compare-versions-in-PostgreSQL.html) for more implementation details.

Comment: Nice work. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot :) 

A small issue though on the `>=` and `<=` operators. They are conflicting with `>` and `<` and should be placed before. As it is, the `= ` part is not done.

Comment: @TitouanFreville you are absolutely right, thanks for debugging. I've also added a test to avoid future regression. Let's update the blogpost now :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use

```
SHOW server_version_num;
```

This returns a version number that's simpler to compare. e.g. 90610 for 9.6.10.

**Update**

Clarifying this answer based on the comments below. The [version number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-preset.html#GUC-SERVER-VERSION-NUM) produced here is machine readable. It is designed to be unique and avoid clashes.

e.g. Postgres version `12.1` will produce `120001` while 12.10 will produce `120010`, etc

https://database.guide/how-to-check-your-postgresql-version/

Comment: This must be used with to much care to be useful, since 9.61.0 would be equal to 9.6.10

Comment: @EdmondLafay-David I don't think so: `096100 ! <> 090610`, maybe the answer lacks a bit of clarity though :/

Comment: indeed, the update to the comment proves me wrong , i'll upvote the answer and the comment (I can't edit my comment, only delete it, which would make the edit confusing)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a pl function, in my case I have used python and distutils.version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION _is_major (a text, b text)
  RETURNS boolean
AS $$
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion 
    return LooseVersion(a) > LooseVersion(b)
$$ LANGUAGE PLPYTHONU;
```

You need the postgresql-plpython package.