# Postgres not allowing ">=" but mysql does, how to overcome?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

My local rails database is mysql but my server host (heroku) is Postgres.
Probably a fairly common combination.

I have an advanced search form that work locally in development mode but not in production and it looks like it might be a Postgres specific thing as the heroku log shows I am getting:

```
    LINE 1: ...,18,19,17,4,32,23,24,16,6,13) and (version_number >= 0.0 or ...
2014-06-23T01:47:54.198026+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2014-06-23T01:47:54.198022+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying >= numeric
2014-06-23T01:47:54.198028+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

in the log.

Is there another way to do >= in postgres.

Locally I do see that the `datatype` is `string` in `schema.rb` which is probably the problem.  Is there a way I can cast it into integer for rails for pg?

Comment: To compare version strings, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223729/compare-software-version-in-postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL definitely does have the `>=` operator: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

Your problem is that you seem to be comparing a string with a number.

> Is there a way I can cast it into integer for rails for pg?

Probably - but we can't see your code. Did you write the SQL? Or did you rely on ActiveRecord? DataMapper? Sequel? Can't help without seeing what you did.