# how to sort a column which contains Semantic Version in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to efficiently store https://semver.org version string in Postgres and then do a latest query . e.g. Say column has values 1.1.0, 1.0.0, 1.2.0, 1.0.1-rc.1+B001 . I would like to sort and get the latest version number (1.2.0) ideally an optimized and performant query as it will be queried frequently.

Note: I would like to sort on a single column and get latest not compare 2 different columns. Also would like it to be full semver compliant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare software version in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223729/compare-software-version-in-postgres)

Comment: @HaleemurAli Thanks thats close, but it does not work for `1.23.45-rc.1+B001` complete semver specs

Comment: @HaleemurAli also that question is comparing 2 columns where as I would like to sort 1 column and get the latest from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accepted answer does work for sorting, but will include e.g. version "10.1" if querying for e.g `version < '2'`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ad031218fe4c941f29c9b03de80d54e0.

If, instead, you define the collation on the column, you get the correct results when filtering by version:

```sql
CREATE COLLATION en_natural (
  LOCALE = 'en-US-u-kn-true',
  PROVIDER = 'icu'
);

CREATE TABLE test (
  version varchar(20) collate en_natural
);

insert into test values
('10.1'),
('2.1'),
('1.2.9'),
('1.24'),
('1.23.231+b'),
('1.23.231+a'),
('1.23'),
('1.23.231-test.beta'),
('1.23.231-test.alpha'),

('1.23.45-rc.2+B001'),
('0.9');

SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE version < '2.0'
ORDER BY version desc;

-- note results do not include 10.1
1.24
1.23.231+b
1.23.231+a
1.23.231-test.beta
1.23.231-test.alpha
1.23.45-rc.2+B001
1.23
1.2.9
0.9
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a284745f2b55617a964c777c29b7e745

Comment: Note: the reason why Laurenz' answer doesn't work as expected when filtering on `WHERE version < '2.0'` while this one DOES, is because Laurenz doesn't use `en_natural` in the definition of the `version` column. Although he uses `en_natural` in `SELECT ... ORDER BY version COLLATE en_natural`, that only applies to the `ORDER BY`, not the `WHERE`. Thus Laurenz' `WHERE` uses the default collation to evaluate `version < '2.0'`, not `en_natural`. Using `en_natural` in column definition as Chris does here avoids that mismatch and eliminates the need to specify `ORDER BY ... COLLATE en_natural`.

Comment: This is not quite right because prereleases with a `-` should be less than (for example, a beta) and the non-prerelease without the `-` should be greater than (for example, the stable) https://runkit.com/embed/kk7mvcduuip3

Answer (score 3):

Try an ICU collation with natural sorting order:

```
CREATE COLLATION en_natural (
   LOCALE = 'en-US-u-kn-true',
   PROVIDER = 'icu'
);
```

Then if you use `ORDER BY somecol COLLATE en_natural`, you should get what you want.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e7945853a6501b4eb1ceea94da3e0b46)

Comment: This is not entirely correct, pre-release version should have lower precedence than a normal version (see https://semver.org/#spec-item-11 /3.)