# How to sort semver in postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, sorting, semantic-versioning

I have a problem with sorting semversions using PostrgreSQL query.

I found topic like this:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74283/how-to-order-by-typical-software-release-versions-like-x-y-z

but they only talk about sorting when semversion is only in a form like MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH,
which is indeed quite easy. But semversion may also include a prerelease (MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH-prerelase).

Quote from here: https://semver.org/

> Precedence for two pre-release versions with the same major, minor,
> and patch version MUST be determined by comparing each dot separated
> identifier from left to right until a difference is found as follows:
>
> 1. Identifiers consisting of only digits are compared numerically.
> 2. Identifiers with letters or hyphens are compared lexically in ASCII
>    sort order.
> 3. Numeric identifiers always have lower precedence than non-numeric
>    identifiers.
> 4. A larger set of pre-release fields has a higher precedence than a
>    smaller set, if all of the preceding identifiers are equal.
>
> Example: 1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta <
> 1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0.

The hard part for me is to create "conditional" sorting which can take two cases into consideration:

- when an identifier consists only digits (numerical comparison should happen)
- when consists only letters or hyphens (ASCII sort order should be used)

and act accordingly to return the correct order.
My table consists two columns: version (major.minor.patch) and prerelease.

It is possible to sort prerelease similar as the version column - by splitting it by a ".", and treating each segment (identifier) as a string, but then there are cases when it doesn't work.

Example:

If we consider semversions like:

```
1.0.0-dev.123, 1.0.0-dev.124, 1.0.0-dev.1234
```

the correct order is :

```
1.0.0-dev.123, 1.0.0-dev.124, 1.0.0-dev.1234
```

whereas when we compare them as strings the output will be:

```
1.0.0-dev.123, 1.0.0-dev.1234, 1.0.0-dev.124
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/doc/semver.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67170865/how-to-sort-a-column-which-contains-semantic-version-in-postgres

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Sometimes you cannot use libraries.
So the idea is to lpad the numerical identifiers with zeros, so they all contain the same amount of characters and then sort them like strings.

My functions are following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numerical_identifier_pad (string text)
    RETURNS text AS
        '
        DECLARE
            result text;
        BEGIN
            IF string ~ ''^[0-9]{1,20}$'' THEN
                result :=  lpad(string, 20, ''0'');
            ELSE
                result := string;
            END IF;

            RETURN result;
        END;
        '
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pad_numeric_identifiers_with_zeros (prerelease_column text)
    RETURNS text AS
        '
        DECLARE
            result text;
        BEGIN
            SELECT array_agg(a.numerical_identifier_pad)
                INTO result
                FROM (
                    SELECT numerical_identifier_pad(
                        unnest(string_to_array(prerelease_column, ''.'')::text[])
                    )
                ) AS a;

            RETURN result;
        END;
        '
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    IMMUTABLE;
```

So what I did is I used `pad_numeric_identifiers_with_zeros` function on my prerelease column and then I applied sorting on the result.

Let's say we have prereleases like in the example from my first post.

- dev.123
- dev.124
- dev.1234

`pad_numeric_identifiers_with_zeros` would do something like this:

- dev.0123
- dev.0124
- dev.1234