# Compare software version strings using EF Core and Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am using .NET Core 3.1, [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.9) and [Npgsql 4.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/4.1.9). `ProductRelease` database entity has a `version` column - a string of numbers separated by a dot in `major.minor.build.revision` format. I would like to retrieve all the records where `version <= 12.5.3.102197`.

```cs
[Table("product_release", Schema = "test")]
public partial class ProductRelease
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Column("version")]
    [StringLength(32)]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223729/compare-software-version-in-postgres) where it is explained how to do it in raw SQL with `string_to_array` built-in function like this:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test.product_release pr
WHERE
    string_to_array(pr.version, '.')::int[] <= string_to_array('12.5.3.102197', '.')::int[];
```

How can I translate this query to EF Core (Npgsql). Is there a way to call `string_to_array` function from EF Core? I would like to avoid writing raw SQL queries.

Comment: Better introduce new SQL Function and map it in EF Core.

Comment: There's current no translation to string_to_array - you can open an issue on https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg to request that this be added.

Comment: I submitted a feature request: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2636